# How do I paint over marble chip plaster?

Tags: walls, painting, paint, repainting

I've moved into my new home, which has a marble chip plaster wall:

[image]

[Source](http://www.dreamstime.com/royalty-free-stock-photos-marble-chip-plaster-close-up-image17269798)

Is it possible to paint over a wall like this, and how would I do that? I've been told that it requires special treatment, but not what kind exactly.

Comment: Do you want a textured or smooth surface?

Comment: @bib, textured is fine. It's just the color that I want to change.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to plaster that before painting it. I'd give it a few months if you haven't just in case it grows on you - it's an expensive and unique finish, and it's going to be expensive to change, with no way to go back.